# StackOverflowException in Microsoft.Html.MainHtmlController on Merge, Annotate,

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I am extending VisualStudio 2015 Html Editor. I've decorated my `IOleCommandTarget` implementing command filter with `[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.PrimaryDocument)]` attribute. This way my commands will not be run in Annotate and Merge TextViews. However I've ran into problem that `MainHtmlController` starts to loop on itself as soon as I open Annotate or Merge window. This is my stacktrace:

[image: Stacktrace when StackOwerflow happens.]

I have no idea what information could be of help here. My contentype definition looks like this. There is 'htmlx' so that html editor handles the file type.

```
public class DothtmlContentTypeDefinition
{
    public const string ContentTypeName = "dothtml";
    //public const string JavaScriptContentType = "JavaScript";
    //public const string CSharpContentType = "cs";

    [Export(typeof(ContentTypeDefinition))]
    [Name(ContentTypeName)]
    [BaseDefinition("htmlx")]
    public ContentTypeDefinition DothtmlContentType { get; set; }

    [Export(typeof(FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition))]
    [FileExtension(".dothtml")]
    [ContentType(ContentTypeName)]
    public FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition DothtmlFileExtensionDefinition { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In my desperation I've tried this:

```
if (textView.Roles.Any(r => r == "VSMERGEDEFAULT_LEFT" || r == "VSMERGEDEFAULT_RIGHT" || r == "ANNOTATE")) {
            ServiceManager.RemoveService<HtmlMainController>(textView);
            return; }
```

But that is the most ugly solution ever. And it causes null exceptions somewhere in `CommandTargetToOleShim` which does not look good. These however are non-fatal and dont take whole visualstudio down. Merge and Annotate are atleast usable.

If needed I will provide more info, but I have no idea what may be relevant.

Comment: Do you have any recursive call?

Comment: What do you mean? Of course I do, hunderds actually ;)

Comment: StackoverflowExceptions occurs when you have recursive calls and they don't hit the base case. You may want to check your recursive calls if this is happening... From the code that you pasted I can't see it. From the screenshot look that he method QueryStatus is called over and over, that probably could give you a hint.